# Number of points in an interval with quadratic spacing

Tags: real-numbers

Suppose I want to distribute unknown points $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n\}$ on an interval $[\lambda_\text{min}, \lambda_\text{max}]$ (on the real line) with spacing $\delta\lambda_i:=\lambda_{i+1}-\lambda_i$ given by
$$\delta\lambda_i=\lambda_i^2$$
and $\lambda_1=\lambda_\text{min}$ and $\lambda_n=\min\{\lambda_\text{max},\lambda_{n-1}+\lambda_{n-1}^2\}$.

**My question is**: Can we find $n:=|\{\lambda_i\}|$, the number of such points?

I have tried setting up an implicit equation
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i}^{n-1}\delta\lambda_i&=\lambda_\text{max}-\lambda_\text{min}\\
\Rightarrow\quad\sum_{i}^{n-1}\lambda_i^2&=\lambda_\text{max}-\lambda_\text{min}
\end{align}$$
but I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: Can't you just start with $\lambda_1 = \lambda_{min}$ and then recursively define $\lambda_{i+1} = \lambda_i + \delta\lambda_i$ until you are done?

Comment: Yes, I could do that (essentially writing a computer program which uses a loop and returns $n$), but I was looking more for a closed-form expression for $n$ in terms of $\lambda_\text{min}$ and $\lambda_\text{max}$.